# understand self for attr_accessor class method

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

```
class Test
  class << self
    attr_accessor :some

    def set_some
      puts self.inspect
      some = 'some_data'
    end
    def get_some
      puts self.inspect
      some
    end
  end
end

Test.set_some => Test
puts Test.get_some.inspect => Test nil
```

Here above I could find self as Test itself but not returning the `some_data` as output.

But while I modified in following way it returns expected output

```
class Test
  class << self
    attr_accessor :some

    def set_some
      puts self.inspect
      self.some = 'some_data'
    end
    def get_some
      puts self.inspect
      self.some
    end
  end
end

Test.set_some => Test
puts Test.get_some.inspect => Test some_data
```

What is the differences?

### EDIT

Now in the first example if I set as get `some` method as

```
Test.some = 'new_data'
puts Test.some.inspect #=> new_data
Test.set_some
puts Test.get_some.inspect => new_data
```

Now it made me much more confused.

Comment: `some = 'some_data'` in first example is only a local variable, assigning of instance variable should use self as receiver (as in second example) or with @ sign (like `@some = 'some_data'`).

Answer (score 12):

`some = :foo` makes ruby think it should create a new local variable with name `some`. If you want to call `some=()`, you have to use an explicit reciever - as in `self.some = :foo`. I once lost a bet on that... :-/

Answer (score 1):

It's (local) variable in the first example

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `some` is a local variable.

In the second one, `some` is a method of `self`. Why? Because `attr_accessor :some` is the same as:

```
def some= (val)
  @some = val
end

def some
  return @some
end
```

So, you have created the getter and setter methods for the instance variable `@some` (it's an instance variable of the object `Test`, as every class is also an object of class `Class`).

Comment: But in the first example I could set value for `some` as `Test.some = 'new_data'`. Which means `some` getter and setter method is class methods. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

in the first method

```
def set_some
  puts self.inspect
  some = 'some_data'
end
```

some is a local variable.. its not the same as @some that is a instance variable (in this case a class instance variable) so the value disappears when the method ends.

if you want to call the setter method some or set @some to something then do this

```
@some = 'some_data'
```

or

```
self.some = 'some_data'
```

in the second method

```
def get_some
  puts self.inspect
  self.some
end
```

your calling the method some. which returns the instace variable @some.. and since at this point @some has no value.. returns nil..

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1** with no method override and no local variable

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @foo = 'foo'
  end

  def print_foo
    print @foo
    print self.foo
    print foo
  end
end
```

@foo, self.foo, and foo will access instance variable @foo within the instance method:

> > Foo.new.print_foo #=> foofoofoo

**Example 2** with method override

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @foo = 'foo'
  end

  def foo
    return 'bar'
  end

  def print_foo
    print @foo
    print self.foo
    print foo
  end
end
```

@foo will access the instance variable, but self.foo and foo will call the foo override method:

> > Foo.new.print_foo #=> foobarbar

**Example 3** with method override and local variable

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @foo = 'foo'
  end

  def foo
    return 'bar'
  end

  def print_foo
    foo = 'baz'
    print @foo
    print self.foo
    print foo
  end
end
```

@foo accesses instance variable, self.foo accesses override method, and foo accesses local variable:

> > Foo.new.print_foo #=> foobarbaz